# Insert Sub Query in 4 Join Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following query in my database which works fine and returns the data I need:

```
PARAMETERS [queryDate] DateTime = Date();
SELECT [Supplier Details].[Supplier Name] AS [Supplier Name], [Coster Suppliers].[Supplier Name] AS [Coster Supplier Name], [Product Details].[Product ID] AS [Product Details_Product ID], [Product Details].[Product Name], [Product Details].[Product Order Sheet Sequence], [Product Details].[Supplier ID], [Product Details].[Product Specification], [Product Details].[Supplier Order Code], [Product Details].[Hide Product], [Product Details].[Coster Supplier ID], [Product Details].[Hide Product from Stock], [Product Details].[Replacement Product ID], [Product Details].[Replacement Product Conversion Factor], [Product Details].[Product PLU], [Known Product Prices for Date Query].[Price Effective from Date], [Known Product Prices for Date Query].[Pack Count], [Known Product Prices for Date Query].[Pack Size], [Known Product Prices for Date Query].[Product Price], [Product Details].[Unit of Measure]
FROM ([Coster Suppliers] RIGHT JOIN ([Supplier Details] INNER JOIN [Product Details] ON [Supplier Details].[Supplier ID] = [Product Details].[Supplier ID]) ON [Coster Suppliers].[Supplier ID] = [Product Details].[Coster Supplier ID]) INNER JOIN [Known Product Prices for Date Query] ON [Product Details].[Product ID] = [Known Product Prices for Date Query].[Product ID];
```

My problem is that the field [Coster Suppliers].[Supplier Name] AS [Coster Supplier Name] comes from another query which I need to insert into this query as a select statement but I do not know where it should go. I am having major issues inserting it and I am sure it is a simple syntax issue. The query to insert instead of referencing it is as follows:

```
SELECT [Coster Supplier Details].[Supplier ID], [Coster Supplier Details].[Supplier Type ID], [Coster Supplier Details].[Supplier Name], [Coster Supplier Details].[Supplier Purchase Tracker Sequence], [Coster Supplier Details].[Supplier Rep], [Coster Supplier Details].[Supplier Account Number], [Coster Supplier Details].[Supplier Sales Hotline], [Coster Supplier Details].[Supplier Sales Fax], [Coster Supplier Details].[Produce new week's order summary based on previous week], [Coster Supplier Details].[Supplier Phone], [Coster Supplier Details].[Supplier Fax], [Coster Supplier Details].[Supplier E-Mail], [Coster Supplier Details].[Supplier Web], [Coster Supplier Details].[Supplier Address 1], [Coster Supplier Details].[Supplier Address 2], [Coster Supplier Details].[Supplier Address 3], [Coster Supplier Details].[Supplier City], [Coster Supplier Details].[Supplier County], [Coster Supplier Details].[Supplier Postcode], [Coster Supplier Details].[Supplier Country], [Coster Supplier Details].[Minimum Order Value], [Coster Supplier Details].[Standard Delivery Cost], [Coster Supplier Details].[Delivery Cost if order value < minimum], [Coster Supplier Details].[Supplier Notes], [Coster Supplier Details].[Hide Supplier], [Coster Supplier Details].[Coster Supplier], [Coster Supplier Details].[Supplier Integration 1], [Coster Supplier Details].[Supplier Integration 2], [Coster Supplier Details].[Accounts Ref]
FROM [Supplier Details] AS [Coster Supplier Details]
WHERE [Coster Supplier Details].[Coster Supplier]=True;
```

I know it would be simple to just reference the query but I cannot do that for various dull and boring reasons.

To further complicate this it is access 2003. The last great version of MS Office.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add another query as a subquery and join to the original query like the below:

```
`SELECT [cds].[Supplier ID]
      , [cds].[Supplier Type ID]
      , [sup].[Supplier Name]
      , [cds].[Supplier Purchase Tracker Sequence]
      , [cds].[Supplier Rep]
      , [cds].[Supplier Account Number]
      , [cds].[Supplier Sales Hotline]
      , [cds].[Supplier Sales Fax]
      , [cds].[Produce new week's order summary based on previous week]
      , [cds].[Supplier Phone]
      , [cds].[Supplier Fax]
      , [cds].[Supplier E-Mail]
      , [cds].[Supplier Web]
      , [cds].[Supplier Address 1]
      , [cds].[Supplier Address 2]
      , [cds].[Supplier Address 3]
      , [cds].[Supplier City]
      , [cds].[Supplier County]
      , [cds].[Supplier Postcode]
      , [cds].[Supplier Country]
      , [cds].[Minimum Order Value]
      , [cds].[Standard Delivery Cost]
      , [cds].[Delivery Cost if order value < minimum]
      , [cds].[Supplier Notes]
      , [cds].[Hide Supplier]
      , [cds].[Coster Supplier]
      , [cds].[Supplier Integration 1]
      , [cds].[Supplier Integration 2]
      , [cds].[Accounts Ref]
FROM [Supplier Details] AS [cds]
JOIN
(
    SELECT [Supplier ID]
         , [Supplier Name] 
    FROM [Other Query]
) [sup]
    ON [cds].[Supplier ID] = [sup].[Supplier ID]

WHERE [cds].[Coster Supplier]=True;`
```

Comment: Thanks for the time Samuel. What I actually want to do is insert the second query into the first but I am getting syntax errors when I do and I do not know where to insert the second query.

Comment: @BobtheBookie If you are using subqueries you have to have the full syntax "select ... from ..." and at the end of the brackets you have to give it an alias.

Comment: @BobtheBookie in your query you have "( table RIGHT JOIN" but it needs to be "( SELECT * FROM table ) tableA RIGHT JOIN...."

Comment: Thank you Samuel. Spot on. It was the position of the sub query that I did not know. Works a treat. Cheers!